# ¿por qué se presenta el Error ORA-01424 solo en una BD con una misma consulta ejecutada en diferentes base de datos Oracle 11g?

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat

Tengo una consulta SQL que se ejecuta correctamente en varias base de datos Oracle 11g, pero en solo una falla.
¿Cuál puede ser la causa que falle la misma consulta sobre solo una base de datos con la misma versión Oracle 11g?

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT ALIAS 
FROM VAR
WHERE ALIAS LIKE '%JOLA/_2018/_PP1/_OC4/_IND4/_C3/_2%' ESCAPE '/';
```

**ERROR:**

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: 
ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character
```

**CONSIDERACIONES:**

1. Todas son versiones Oracle 11g.
2. El error se presenta ejecutando el query desde la WebApp Java 1.6 con Tomcat6.
3. Si se ejecuta el query desde el SQL Developer no se presenta el error.
4. El error se presenta solo en una base datos, en las demás funciona correctamente.

Gracias.

Comment: Carlos, bienvenido a [es.so] muy buena aportación, explicando el problema, mostrando el código y el error. Aunque aparentemente estás familiarizado con el sitio, te recomiendo hacer el [tour], donde explica el funcionamiento de esta comunidad, además conseguirás tu primera medalla!

Comment: La pregunta esta muy bien.. ahora el problema va a ser como reproducir tu escenario :(

Answer (score 0):

Ese problema es muy común y muy sencillo de resolver. No debes incluir el punto y coma (;) al final de la consulta producto que el driver de JDBC de Oracle lo identifica como un caracter no válido.

Comment: Apliqué el cambio que me indicas, pero no me funcionó.

Comment: también hice una actualización del jdbc a su última versión compatible con Java6 y tampoco me solventó el problema